# Exit from docker using make file

Tags: docker, makefile

I am trying to create a make file to run the docker commands.

```
start:
    $(info Make: Starting container.)
    docker run -it --rm -v $(shell pwd):/mnt -w /mnt build:focal
 
stop:
    $(info Make: Stopping container.)
    exit
```

When I run `make start`, the docker container starts and the current directory is `/mnt` but when I run `make stop` it prints exit in the terminal rather than exiting the docker container. So, to stop, I must type exit or ctrl+c again in the terminal. Is it possible to close the container using makefile from inside the container?

```
$make start
Make: Starting container.
docker run -it --rm -v /data/demo:/mnt -w /mnt build
builduser@6a1958f9d0cc:/mnt$ ls
Makefile
builduser@6a1958f9d0cc:/mnt$ make stop
Make: Stopping container.
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `make` this way in general.  You can try it from your host shell: no matter how many times you run `make stop` it will not exit the containing shell.

There's a couple of subprocesses involved here.  `make` itself is a subprocess, and then for each command in each rule it runs `/bin/sh -c` (or something else from the Make `$(SHELL)` variable).  So this command runs `/bin/sh -c 'exit'`, which launches another subprocess.  That shell subprocess exits but nothing else.  If Make had another target to build, it would build it.

Whatever work it is you want to do inside a container, I'd suggest setting up the container to just do that work.  Don't involve an interactive shell.  If you can manage it, try to avoid having a long-running container that you execute multiple commands in; instead, run one-off containers with `docker run --rm`.

```
BUILD_IMAGE := image

some-file.txt:
        docker run --rm -v $(PWD):/data -w /data $(BUILD_IMAGE) \
          touch some-file.txt

some-file-2.txt: some-file.txt
        docker run --rm -v $(PWD):/data -w /data $(BUILD_IMAGE) \
          sh -c 'cat some-file.txt some-file.txt > some-file-2.txt'
```

Rather than try to invoke Docker from within your Makefile, it may be easier to write a "normal" Makefile, then run the whole thing in a container.

```
some-file.txt:
        touch "$@"

some-file-2.txt: some-file.txt
        cat "$<" "$<" > "$@"
```

```bash
docker run -v "$PWD:/build" -w /build build-image make
```

Comment: `Don't involve an interactive shell`, My use case I need to mount the project to a docker container and run the script to build the project.Currently I am using interactive shell to enter inside the container build the code and run the generated binaries inside docker.

Comment: The very last command I show would do that.  You could run any single command in the temporary container by replacing `make` at the end.  I wouldn't generally suggest a Makefile as a general-purpose task runner, since it has a couple of syntactic oddities, but you could write a shell script or a Dockerfile to do the work instead (a Dockerfile that `COPY`s the source code in without mounting anything might work well).

Comment: Ok I will try to follow the above commands.Regarding the `COPY` command the project is huge so its taking time for the copy so I mounted to the container.

Comment: The reason for choosing the makefile is I have very big command to run the docker container with `docker run -it --ip 192.168.7.20 --net=run--network --rm -u 0 -v $(pwd):/mnt -v /tmp:/tmp --name build_$(whoami) build:focal` so instead of running this command I taught to put into make file and run the make target.